# Improve import speed of azure analysis services model

Tags: azure-analysis-services, azure-synapse

I currently have an azure analysis services model deployed as

1. S4 instance that pulls data from synapse data warehouse
2. data warehouse is at at DWU5000c level
3. database connection permitted in the xlargerc resource group to permit using up to 70% of the available DWU to pull in data

Across the entire model there are only 200 columns in total and the table sizes are as:

```
[Basket] -- 42,628,410        9 column
[Coupon] -- 238,686,562       37 columns
[Dim_Calendar] -- 14,245      na
[Dim_Product] -- 40,905,055   12 columns
[Discount] -- 9,096           na
[Item] -- 408,550,310         53 columns
[Tender] -- 54,053,087        39 columns
```

At present, when I try to import a single table, say basket, it will only import just under 150,000 records a second.

Is there a mass bulk import setting I am missing? How can I alter the settings to improve the import speed?

Comment: A few things to rule out: can you confirm you've deployed the tabular model and you're trying to refresh it in Azure, not import to Visual Studio?  Is the database and the tabular model in the same region?  Is the account you're connecting with not the database admin account (these default to smallrc irrespective)?  If you connect to the database and run queries there, what is the performance like? No wide text columns or identity columns in your large tables?  What is the distribution in Synapse SQL Pools?  Your tabular model is in Import not DirectQuery? Considered partitioning in the model?

Comment: Any update on this?  Shall I promote this to an answer?  Thanks

Comment: Turns out using xlargerc was the problem, it used 70% for each query not 70% altogether, so forced into sequential execution

Comment: Ah ok, consider switching to static resource class (eg staticrc50) or smaller dynamic resource class eg mediumrc) depending on your requirements / data volumes.  Consider posting as a self answer so your learning is useful to others?  : )

Comment: The technique for detecting the queuing eg via DMVs would be useful to post?

Comment: @wBob I used the Azure portal to see everything pushed to queue, yes, went to mediumrc